# How to secure specific folders on a portable SSD that works on multiple devices?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, encryption

I use a portable SSD with different devices such as Windows PCs and Samsung TVs. Some of the folders on the SSD have sensitive or personal data that I want to protect. How can I encrypt, password-protect, or restrict access to these folders only, without affecting the rest of the SSD or its compatibility with other devices?

I tried BitLocker, but it encrypts the whole SSD and makes it unusable on non-Windows devices, such as my Samsung TV.

Is there a way to use BitLocker or something similar on specific folders only? Or is there another solution that can do what I want?

I have found some solutions, such as [VeraCrypt] and [Folder Lock], but I'm not sure if they work well with portable SSDs and different devices as they are talking about partition encrypting/locking rather than securing a specific folders.

How can I secure specific folders on a portable storage device that will work on multiple systems?

Comment: I would recommend against such a setup, instead get an additional drive you exclusively use with TVs and all that and one to keep your sensitive data. Anyway, you're basically asking for software recommendations, no?

Answer (score 2):

Veracrypt is your best option as it can be made to work on Windows, PC, and I believe Mac.  That said **it is unlikely that it will work on devices like Samsung TV's - indeed, I think it's unlikely any general crypto solution will work with them.

The issue is not one of portable devices - it's one of software support for the encryption standard. Veracrypt is pretty device-agnostic - indeed on Linux at least it's an abstraction layer of the block device, so it can sit on top any block device.